# Python Scipy Kernel Density Estimate Smoothing Issues

Tags: python, scipy, kernel-density

Sorry to ask a question with probably a very obvious answer but I'm a bit confused as to how to tweak how much I can smooth with the KDE. My code looks something like this in python:

```
kde = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(c)
P_0 = kde(3)
P_c = kde(c)
```

where c is just a column of numbers and I want to do an integral with the above (that's not too important for the problem I'm having). I'm a bit confused as to how I would change the scott/silverman method in scipy to allow a bit of over/undersmoothing.

Comment: That's very broad. You can just put float-values (as smoothing parameter) set as param ```bw_method```. Apart from that it's not really clear what you want to do. Using some alternatives, cross-validation is easier to use (sklearn -> random and grid-search; statsmodels -> optimization-based).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want to tweak the [set_bandwidth](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.set_bandwidth.html) parameter. That link contains simple example code, which I reduce here to the most basic elements:

```
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(c)
kde.set_bandwidth(bw_method=.3)
P = kde(c)
```

So basically, the bandwidth is set via the `kde.set_bandwidth(bw_method=X)` call, where `X` is usually a float or one of the methods `silverman`, `scott`. The full description actually states that `bw_method`:

> can be ‘scott’, ‘silverman’, a scalar constant or a callable. If a scalar, this will be used directly as kde.factor. If a callable, it should take a gaussian_kde instance as only parameter and return a scalar.

Comment: Thank you! Was something odd that I didn't understand about this, but now it makes sense! :)